# Ansible - print gathered facts for debugging purposes

Tags: ansible

Is there exists some way to print on console gathered facts ?
I mean gatering facts using `setup` module. I would like to print gathered facts. Is it possible ? If it is possible can someone show example?

Comment: this command show all facts about a host: 
**ansible -i path_to_inventory -m setup hostname**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) module as `ad-hoc` command:

```
ansible myhost -m setup
```

Comment: ok, however. I have some playbook. And in this playbook I executed `setup` module. Can I check after this execution what facts are gathered?

Comment: run playbook with `-vv` switch?

Comment: I always forget the possibility of using an ad-hoc command.

Comment: There are few issues with this approach: to make any use of this you need to run something like `ansible -v myhost -m setup | grep ansible_hostname` because facts are printed only when verbosity >=1 and grepping because there are too many. Ideally ansible should support chaining modules and doing something like: `ansible -m setup -m debug -a var=ansible_hostname`

Comment: `ansible -i somehost, all -m setup` if you are running this _truly_ ad-hoc and don't even have any inventory. (The trailing `,` is correct)

Comment: I played with mobaxterm-based Ansible controller and I would like to expand @conny 's comment: `ansible -i somehost, all -m setup -u <remote_ssh_user>`. This allowed to connect using certain username without inventory file.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply dump the `hostvars`:

`dump.yml`

```
---
 - name: Dump
   hosts: "{{ target|default('localhost') }}"
   tasks:
   - name: Facts
     setup:
   - name: Dump
     delegate_to: localhost
     run_once: true
     copy:
       content: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | to_nice_json }}"
       dest: /tmp/setup-dump.json
```

Call this playbook with `ansible-playbook dump.yml -e target=hostname` or simply without hostname.

Comment: Thanks, however it seems to don't work.  `TASK [Dump] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost -> localhost]
`I started with target=localhost

Comment: It works. Output is saved in /tmp/setup-dump.json